# Need Query information

Tags: sql

I have several tables

Table Incident

```
 incident_id | Customer_name
 01          | AAA
 02          | BBB
 03          | CCC
 04          | DDD
```

Table Customer

```
 Customer_name | Area_Name | Segment_Name 
 AAA           | JAKARTA   | PETROLEUM
 BBB           | MEDAN     | TRADITIONAL
 CCC           | JAKARTA   | TRADITIONAL
 DDD           | MEDAN     | AIRPORT
```

Table Area

```
 Area_Name | Phone
 JAKARTA   | 021
 MEDAN     | 022
```

The result that expected :

```
 Area    | Segment     | Number (count from Incident tabel)
 JAKARTA | PETROLEUM   | 1
 MEDAN   | TRADITIONAL | 1
 JAKARTA | TRADITIONAL | 1
 MEDAN   | PETROLEUM   | 0
```

any help will be helpfull

Comment: plz provide table structure with data

Comment: @RahulVasantraoKamble : the table structure are so simple. In Incident table, there are customerid, and incident_id. In customer table, there are customerid, new_areaid, new_partnersegment id. In Partnersegment table, there are new_partnersegmentid, new_name

Comment: Your data although simple does not have a Medan with Petroleum combination.  Are you trying to just get a count on per Petroleum and Traditional per area?  Or are you implying that "Airport" means Petroleum and just accidental sample of data.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you always want the area and the segment right?

```
SELECT  c.new_name, d.new_SegmentName, ISNULL(COUNT(a.CustomerId),0) as jumlah
    FROM filterednew_area c  LEFT JOIN filteredaccount b ON b.new_AreaId = c.new_areaId
    LEFT JOIN filterednew_partnersegment d ON b.new_PartnerSegmentId = d.new_partnersegmentId
    LEFT JOIN filteredIncident a ON a.CustomerId = b.AccountId
    WHERE   MONTH(a.new_trxdate) = '10' AND YEAR(a.new_trxdate) = '2012'
    AND c.new_areaid IN ('3C26906E-5C13-E211-8D39-005056850007','4E26906E-5C13-E211-8D39-005056850007')
    GROUP BY    c.new_name, d.new_SegmentName
```

If you always want the area, you should start the join from it.
Try this query.

EDIT: Solution with tables after edit

```
select C.Area_Name, C.Segment_Name, ISNULL(count(I.incident_id), 0)
from customer C left outer join incident I
on C.Customer_name = I.Customer_Name
group by C.Area_Name, C.Segment_Name
```

**EDIT 2:** Solution with cartesian product

To do this I imagine there is a table *Segment* with the possible segment (and i think this kind of table was present in the first query)

```
SELECT A.Area_Name, A.Segment_name, Count(Incident.Incident_Id) AS TOT
FROM
(
(SELECT Distinct Customer.Area_Name, Segment.Segment_name
FROM Segment, Customer 
) AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer AS C
 ON (C.Area_Name = A.Area_Name) AND (C.Segment_name = A.Segment_name)
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Incident ON C.Customer_Name = Incident.Customer_name
GROUP BY A.Area_Name, A.Segment_name;
```

The result of the query is

```
Area_Name  |    Segment_name |  TOT  

JAKARTA    |    AIRPORT     |  0  
JAKARTA    |    PETROLEUM   |   1  
JAKARTA    |    TRADITIONAL |   1  
MEDAN       |    AIRPORT     |  1  
MEDAN       |    PETROLEUM   |  0  
MEDAN       |    TRADITIONAL |  1
```

Comment: your query are still the same when I try it. the result are still 3 data. What I want, the result is come for 4 data, where the last data, is add the 0 data.

Comment: Are you sure exist a link from table C to table D ? That's probably the problem. Could you provide example data you are using for this?

Comment: no, there are no link from table c to table D. the link are through table B. the example and structur data are on above.

Comment: I mean exactly that link through table B. I understood the table strcuture, but i would like to see the actual data.

Comment: how i can attach the actual data in stackoverflow?

Comment: Like you wrote the result you want, write an example tables. I think in table B is missing the row to link table B and table D for MALANG/PETROLEUM

Comment: Is MEDAN - AIRPORT in the example = MEDAN - PETROLEUM? If not, that's the reason for the error, you have no MEDAN - PETROLEUM link in those tables

Comment: thats correct. there are no MEDAN - PETROLEUM data. That's why, I want display it with result : 0.

Comment: added a solution with new tables

Comment: Ok, so you simply can't with this structure

Comment: If you have segment separated from customer, you should create a cartesian product of all the customer/sement combination and then join this resulting data with your tables

Comment: so, the solution can be use? will try it.

Comment: the solution that you give, still not work. can you give me an example to create cartesian product?

Comment: added solution tested on a test db